# Rspec bundler: failed to load command: rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following error when running rspec.

```
bundler: failed to load command: rspec (/home/bastien/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rspec)
NameError: uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Storage::Fog
```

This is the "testing part" of my gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
gem 'rspec'
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
gem 'database_cleaner'
gem 'shoulda-matchers'
gem 'spring'
end
```

I have tried many things to correct this issue including adding to both

```
rails_helper.rb
spec_helper.rb
```

Those various require

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'carrierwave'
require "rails_helper"
require 'rails/all'
require 'rubygems'
```

**EDIT**

Carrierwave initializer file

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
config.fog_credentials = {
provider:               'AWS',
aws_access_key_id:      ENV['S3_KEY'],
aws_secret_access_key:  ENV['S3_SECRET'],
region: 'us-east-1'

}

if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.cucumber?
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
config.storage           = :file
config.enable_processing = false
end
end

config.cache_dir        = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads" 
config.fog_directory    = ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
end
```

Rspec still does not work while the application works fine. Would anyone have an idea of how I can solve this issue? Is there a quick and dirty fix that would allow me to test the other parts of the app by excluding carrierwave-related items? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to google `uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Storage::Fog`? A lot of options: Gemfile, CarrierWave initializer, any place where you configure CarrierWave/Fog depending on Env.

Comment: Hi Bastien.  What does your `initializers/carrierwave.rb` rile look like?

Answer (score 0):

The file generating the issue was in the uploader folder (doc_uploader.rb)

The testing environment was not correctly declared with

```
if Rails.env.development?
  storage :file
else
  storage :fog
end
```

that I had to change into

```
if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
  storage :file
else
  storage :fog
end
```